# mod_rewrite - Folder to parameters

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I like to rewrite a URL but the rules in my .htaccess didn't match. The .htaccess is in the "foo" folder.

There are two kinds of URLs:

```
http://www.domain.com/foo/Fgh34R #Always 6 Chars after the "/" A-Za-z0-9
#should be redirected to
http://www.domain.com/foo/index.php?s=Fgh34R

http://www.domain.com/foo/http://www.google.com
#should be redirected to
http://www.domain.com/foo/index.php?u=http://www.google.com
```

This is my .htaccess so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\/(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?$ index.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^\/([A-Za-z0-9]{0,6})$ index.php?s=$1
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo/(https?://\S+)$ foo/index.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^foo/([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$ foo/index.php?s=$1
```

Comment: Thank you, but i've edited my question. I've forgotten a folder ("foo") in the path. Sorry. Can you look again? Thx.